# Measuring the entropy of a graph representing a transition probability matrix of a first order markov chain

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, markov-chains, entropy

There's a research project i'm currently working on which requires me to analyze various aspects of "worlds" represented by transition probability matrices, where the nodes represent objects in the world that our "learner" travels through.
I'm looking for a way to measure the degree to which the structure of the connections in a given a graph provide the learner with any predictive power, for example, in a graph where all the vertices have the same value, the learner has absolutely no ability to predict the next node/nodes given the current one.

The graphs are all weighted and directed, with the sum of outgoing connections from each node normalized to one.

I'm having a bit of trouble coming up with a good way to measure this and would really appreciate some advice,
Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example (not very nice though):

$P=\begin{pmatrix}1/6&1/2&1/3\\1/2&0&1/2\\0&1/3&2/3\end{pmatrix}$

Eigenvector for eigenvalue 1: $p=(1, 5/3, 7/2)$

Normalization: $p_\text{normalized}=(36/577, 60/577, 126/577)$

So the entropy (after simplifying a little bit by putting together terms) is:

$h(p,P)=-\frac{6}{577}\cdot\log(1/6)-\frac{54}{577}\cdot\log(1/3)-\frac{78}{577}\cdot\log(1/2)-\frac{84}{577}\cdot\log(2/3)$

This gives an approximate real value of:

$h(p,P)\approx 0.274\ldots$

One final thing: If your matrix $P$ has zero entries, the product $P_{i,j}\log P_{i,j}$ will be zero for the corresponding entry, even so the logarithm would be negative infinity (multiplying by zero wins here).

Comment: First of all, thanks for the example, however, when i use matlab to calculate the eigenvector at eigenvalue 1 for this exact same matrix, i get the following vector - [0.5774,0.5774,0.5774], nothing like the vector you show here, maybe were doing something different?

Comment: also, why are you using the values from the top row only in your calculation? i need a value that represents the entropy fort the entire transition probability matrix

Comment: The eigenvector I gave, is a right eigenvector (a row vector) which satiesfies $pP=p$. Since the matrix $P$ is stochastic (meaning that all rows sum to 1) a left eigenvector (that is what you got from Matlab) makes no sense.

Comment: I did use the entire matrix in my computation. The formula for $h_\text{top}$ is already simplified a bit by putting same $\log$ terms together. Not sure what else to explain now...

Comment: a few things:
What is the normalization for and how exactly do i go about doing it? iv'e figured out a way to get the correct stationary distribution, but have no idea what this normalization step means
second, once iv'e got that sorted out, does the "i" in the formula refer to rows or columns?

Comment: The normalization is because you want to compute entropy for a probability measure (i.e. the entire space has to have measure 1). The vector $p$ is the distribution on the vertices of your graph and thus its entries have to sum to the measure of the space. (Think of what would happen to the entropy if you multiplied $p$ by a constant.)

Comment: Well, $P$ is a matrix. What is the standard way to index entries? $P_{i,j}$ means the entry of $P$ at position $i$th row, $j$th column. $p$ is a vector, so there the $i$ just means its $i$th component. (I do get the impression that your mathematical basics are very lacking, that or you are trying to extend this conversation making it go on forever...) Maybe doing a Google search or reading around a bit would help...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your exact question, but there is an explicit formula for the measure theoretic entropy of a first order Markov chain (that is what your directed, weighted graph represents). You need to compute the stationary vector $p$ for your stochastic matrix $P$ (the one given by the weights on your directed graph) and then the formula for the entropy is just:

$h(p,P)=-\sum_{i,j\in V}p_iP_{i,j}\log P_{i,j}$

where the sum runs over all pairs of vertices in your graph, $p_i$ is the initial probability of vertex $i$ and $P_{i,j}$ the transition probability (i.e. the weight of your edge $i,j$).

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the formula correctly, what would $p_i$ represent here exactly? and how would i go about calculating it?

Comment: Little p is an eigenvector of your stochastic matrix P (for the eigenvalue 1).

Comment: I would suggest the book of Walters, Introduction to Ergodic Theory, Theorem 4.27 (or mostly any book on ergodic theory) to learn more about the entropy formula for a Markov chain.

Comment: As stated above, i do not have a very rich mathematical background, and need this calculation for a certain project i'm working on, i'd prefer a simple answer in layman terms, as i beleive any book on the subject would be quite above my level. what i don't understand in the above equation, is what value to use for p_i when calculating the sum

Comment: Do you know what an eigenvector is?

Comment: As far as calculating it and the general A v = \lambda v conjecture, yes i do.

Comment: I want to see if i got this one right, i calculate the matrix(P_ij*LOG(P_ij) using elementwise multiplication, then i multiply each eigenvector by this matrix, sum all of this up and mulitply by -1?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. You take the matrix $P_{i,j}$ given by the weights on you graph, you compute an eigenvector for the eigenvalue 1 of this matrix, i.e. you take the equation $p*P=1*p$ (where $p$ is a row vector) and such that the "length" (i.e. norm) of $p$ is one. Then you have all the numbers to compute your entropy. Plug in everything in the formula above and you get the corresponding non-negative real number.

Comment: If you want just try an example (with a small graph/matrix) and put your steps here so I can tell you whether it is correct or not.

Comment: what if there is no eigenvector for which the eigenvalue is 1?

Comment: heres an example of the steps i took with an example matrix:
1) Calculate eigenvector (largest, with norm = 1)
2) elementwise multiplication of matrix with log(matrix)
3) multiply said eigenvector with the result of the elementwise multiplication
4) sum up the result, multiply by -1

using this method iv'e gotten some negative values for several of my original (non random) matrices, what would that mean?

Comment: First, if your matrix is a stochastic matrix, i.e. all row sums are equal to 1, then there will be an eigenvector for eigenvalue 1.

Comment: Second, the formula for the entropy will give you a single non-negative real number, not a matrix, so I don't understand why you are saying some of the values are negative.

Comment: Here is an example:

Comment: i am getting a single number, however iv'e performed this calculation for about 100 matrices, and some of the values produced were negative,